# Adding child to Firebase console is NOT working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am adding child to my app but its not being added to the Firebase console
[image: SEE THE IMAGE HERE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter a value and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.